# pandas df: replace values with np.NaN if character count do not match across multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

currently stuck with something I hope to find an answer for in this forum:

- I have a df with multiple columns containing URLs. My index column are URLs as well.
- AIM: I'd like to replace df values across all columns with np.NaN if the number of "/" (count()) in the index is not equal to the number of "/" (count()) in the values of each individual of of the other columns

E.x.

[image: Table lookalike]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Ok found a way by using:
`for i in df.columns:
    
    df.loc[df.index.str.count("/") != df[i].str.count("/"), i] = np.NaN`. thanks anyway

Comment: There is a more efficient way to achieve what you want. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need one column to compare to.

```
 counts = df['id_url'].str.count('/')
```

Then you evaluate all the rows at once.

```
 mask = df.str.count('/') == counts
```

Then we want to to show rows where all the values are equal.

```
 mask = mask.all(axis=1)
```

Now we have a mask for where every value is equal, we can use the not operator to filter for those where at least one column is not equal.

```
 df.loc[~mask, :] = np.nan # replaces every value in the row with np.nan
```